# How to set the delegate of initial ViewController in a storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, uistoryboard

I have a Storyboard like this:

```
-- initial --> [PictureListViewController] ----> [PictureDetailViewController]
```

Now I want to set the delegate of my ViewController `PictureListViewController`. Since it is the first ViewController I can't do this in the method `-(void)prepareForSegue:...` since I the initial ViewController is created by the Storyboard framework.

For re-usability I also don't want the `PictureListViewController` so set it's own `delegate`.

What is the best practise for this. I could of course create another "empty" ViewController which then segues to the `PictureListViewController` but this does not feel like the right thing to do for me.

Your help is very welcome. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set this in the App Delegate by grabbing a reference to your root view controller using...

```
YourFirstViewController *ctr = self.window.rootViewController;
// Do stuff here
```